# ClosedXML Master-Deatail-Report

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

community:

I'm implementing ClosedXML in C# and I've a query that brings me a set of structured data in the following way:

```
[
   {
       "CustNo":"1",
       "Company":"Name Company",
       ...,
       "Orders": [
                  {
                      "OrderNo":"1",
                      "SaleDate":"10-May-23",
                      ...,
                      "Items":[
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 }
                              ]
                  },
                  {
                      "OrderNo":"2",
                      "SaleDate":"10-May-23",
                      ...,
                      "Items":[
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 }
                              ]
                  }
               ]
   },
   {
       "CustNo":"2",
       "Company":"Name Company",
       ...,
       "Orders": [
                  {
                      "OrderNo":"1",
                      "SaleDate":"10-May-23",
                      ...,
                      "Items":[
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 }
                              ]
                  },
                  {
                      "OrderNo":"2",
                      "SaleDate":"10-May-23",
                      ...,
                      "Items":[
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "ItemNo":"1",
                                     "Description":"Name Item",
                                     ...
                                 }
                              ]
                  }
               ]
   }
]
```

The problem is that when generating the Excel, it only fills in the first level, {{item.CustomNo}} and {{item.Company}}, but it doesn't print the Orders or Items level. It just leaves them blank. I used the Nested Ranges: Master-detail Report structure provided in the documentation, but it only includes the template and not the data that needs to be compared.

[image]

Can someone help me by telling me how to access the Orders or Items level from Excel, or if you could provide me with the data used in the Master-detail example from the documentation, I would greatly appreciate it!

I tried to create named ranges in Excel, one for each branch, but it still doesn't show me the information for orders or items. I also tried to do it like {{items.Orders.OrderNo}}.

Comment: According to [ClosedXML documentation](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml#developer-guidelines): _ClosedXML the wrapper around OpenXML_. Therefore, one may find the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to be helpful.

Comment: hello ;) did You figured it out? i have similar issue...